# JxBrowser exception

Tags: java, swing, browser, jxbrowser

I run the JxBrowser sample, and I'd the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPC.getDefault(SourceFile:45)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.BrowserContext.<init>(SourceFile:63)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.BrowserContext.<clinit>(SourceFile:25)
at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser.<init>(SourceFile:137)
at BrowserSample.main(BrowserSample.java:14)
```

The code is:

```
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class BrowserSample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Browser browser = new Browser();
    BrowserView browserView = new BrowserView(browser);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(browserView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(700, 500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    browser.loadURL("http://www.google.com");
}
}
```

I think, you can help me.
I'd all JAR archives and license file **(!)**

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: I think you must check that you are importing the right jar into your file system I'm on windows so i have: jxbrowser-6.14.jar, jxbrowser-win32-6.14.jar and license.jar. Could you please confirm this?

Comment: The ExceptionInInitializerError stack trace is just a part. You should see more output in console and more exception stack traces. Could you please publish all console output you see. I suppose the issue is in missing or expired license.

Comment: @sirandy                                                                                                      I use Jxbrowser 6.14.  The console output is very **_big (!)_**.

Comment: are you running on an macosx? maybe you have to initialize in an non-ui thread?

Comment: I'm running on Windows.